# cache application ASP.NET MVC BY Different Url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have an application asp.net mvc that has different url addresses. That is, as the address changes, the data displayed on the page also changes.
I'm using OutputCache for server side cache information.
how resolve this problem
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `VaryByParam` to specify a semicolon-delimited list of query string or form POST parameters that the output cache uses to vary the cache entry.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "parameter")]
public ActionResult Index(string parameter)
```